# In Ajax HTMLEditor, How to remove some buttons from toolbar?

Tags: ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using `Ajax HTMLEditor` control, but I want to show only 3 `buttons` in `toolbar`. How to remove some unnecessary buttons from toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution [Link](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/how-do-i-use-the-html-editor-control-cs)